# How to Make Visual Studio C++ 2010 Compilation Behave Like gcc/g++? (or vice-versa)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Say you've got the following simple main.cpp file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const string FILENAME = "foo.txt";
    ifstream somefile(FILENAME);
    populations.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine via Visual Studio C++ 2010.

However, on a Linux-based system, if I execute `make main` and compile, we get an expected error since we didn't call `c_str()` on the string constant, like so:

```
ifstream somefile(FILENAME.c_str());
```

As is commonly known, and described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662624/c-ifstream-open-problem-with-passing-a-string-for-text-file-name).

How can I get VS to behave like gcc/g++ and raise a compilation error for the code above? Or, how can I get gcc/g++ to behave like VS and compile the above without error? (Is it a simple matter of upgrading my gnu compiler?)

(I don't believe disabling compiler extensions is a solution, as I've done this and it still compiles without error.)

Comment: The question was asked long before C++0x came out.

Comment: Why don't you make gcc behave like VS?

Comment: @ybakos: ugrade gcc to have a newer libstdc++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060034/vs2010-c-and-c-enforce-ansi-compliance-for-linux-gcc-compatibility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *is* available as part of the newer c++ standard.

To disable, add

```
  #define _HAS_CPP0X 0
```

at the top before your includes.

Comment: This does work, although I recognize it's probably better for me to upgrade by gnu toolkit.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio behaves correctly in this case with respect to the C++11 standard ([it works on g++ now, too](http://ideone.com/VAXKA)). I'm not sure why would you want to do this, but you'll probably need to edit MSVC's headers (not advisable and rather drastic).

Strange thing is though, that [they don't write it in their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8et8s826.aspx). Can you check which constructor is actually being called?

Comment: It goes into: explicit basic_ifstream(const string& _Str,
  ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in,
  int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot)

Comment: Thanks for this insight jpalecek.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the documentation under basic_ifstream either: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zek0beca(v=VS.100).aspx